# jquery - How to create a variable name from a function argument

Tags: jquery, function, variables, dynamic, arguments

In a function I want to create a variable that consists of some text + the argument submitted with the function. For example:

```
function adjust($id){
   var bh = parseFloat($('#body_data').css('height')) / 12;
   var nt = $('#fs_notice' + $id).offset().top / 12;
   var nh+$id = bh - nt; // variable name should be "nh1" when $id = 1, "nh2" when $id = 2 and so on...
   ...
}
```

I hope that I described my little problem sufficiently!

Can anybody give me some advice on how to achieve that?

Comment: Why not just use an array and index it with `$id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define in window

```
window[nh+$id] = bh - nt;
```

You can also use arrays defined in window scope, where $id is supposed to be incremented index.

```
var arr = [];
function adjust($id){
   var bh = parseFloat($('#body_data').css('height')) / 12;
   var nt = $('#fs_notice' + $id).offset().top / 12;
   var arr[$id] = bh - nt; // variable name should be "nh1" when $id = 1, "nh2" when $id = 2 and so on...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local object also.
For example:

```
function adjust($id){
 var obj={}, variableString = "nh" + $id;
 var bh = 3;
 var nt = 2;
 obj[variableString] = bh - nt;
 ...//Use obj[variableString] going fwd
 }
```

Created a sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vB4M7/13/